# авторизация с данными из файла

Tags: php, авторизация

Какой код нужен для входа уже зарегистрированного пользователя? Я создал файл, в который заносятся данные из 13 полей формы. Преподаватель требует, чтобы я из этого файла брал данные для входа. На всякий случай, помещаю свой код с формой и файлом:

```
<?php
session_start ();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <meta charset = "utf-8">
                <title>Задание к уроку 14</title>

        <style>

            option:nth-child(odd){
                color:red; font-weight: normal;
            }
            option:nth-child(even){
                color:blue; font-weight: normal;
            }

            .rad{
                border: 4px solid blue;
                width: 600px;
            }

            .span1{
                color: yellow;
                font-style: italic;
                font-size: 120%;
            }


            :focus::-webkit-input-placeholder{color: transparent}
            :focus::-moz-placeholder{color: transparent}
            :focus:-moz-placeholder{color: transparent}
            :focus:-ms-placeholder{color: transparent}

            .but2{color:red;}

            body{
                background-image: url('for12.jpg');
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: cover;
                color: #FDFAFD;
            }

            .ins1{
                background-color: #F1FCC7;
                font-weight: 800;
            }
            .reg1{
                position: fixed;
                background-color: yellow;
                width: 10%;
                font-size: 150%;
                color: blue;
                padding: 0px 10px;
            }

            #div1{
                border: 2px solid black;
            box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px black;
            padding: 0px 10px;
            background-color: blue;
            color: white;
            }
            #out{
                background-color: green;
                font-weight: bold;
                color: white;
                padding: 5px;
                font-size: 150%;
            }
            #sp1{font-size: 150%;
            color: red;
            background-color: yellow;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
        function sb1(){
            document.getElementById('log1').value = "";
            document.getElementById('fn').value = "";
            document.getElementById('sn').value = "";
            document.getElementById('mn').value = "";
            document.getElementById('s1').checked = false;
            document.getElementById('s2').checked = false;
            document.getElementById('d1').value = "";
            document.getElementById('m1').value = "";
            document.getElementById('y1').value = "";
            document.getElementById('t1').value = "";
            document.getElementById('c1').checked = false;
            document.getElementById('c2').checked = false;
            document.getElementById('ps1').value = "";
            document.getElementById('ps2').value = "";
        }
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div class = "reg1"><b>Регистрация</b></div><br><br>


    <?php

    $login = $_POST['logged'];
    $pass = md5($_POST['pass']);
    $pass2 = md5($_POST['passd']);

    if($_POST['out'] === "Выход")
    {
        unset($_SESSION['log']);
        session_destroy();
    }


    if(
    ($_POST['logged'] === $login)&&(md5($_POST['pass']) === $pass)&&(md5($_POST['passd']) === $pass2)
    )
    {
        $_SESSION['log'] = $_POST['logged'];
        $_SESSION['pas'] = md5($_POST['pass']);
        $_SESSION['pas2'] = md5($_POST['passd']);

    }
    else {echo "<span id='sp1'>Пароль и/или логин не введены или неверные!</span><br>";} ?>

    <!--Чтобы обойтись без echo изолируем php и html-->
    <form action = "./HWL14_db.php" method = "post"> <!--Первая форма-->
    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['log'])&&(md5($_POST['pass']) === md5($_POST['passd']))):?>  <!--Условие-->

    <!-- Ниже то, что выводится в случае выполнения условия-->
    <?php echo "Приветствуем Вас ".$_SESSION['log']."!<br>\n";?>
    <input id = "out" type = "submit" name = "out" value = "Выход"><br><br>
    </form> <!--Форма закрылась-->

    <div id = "div1">
    <!-- Это  создание файла и вывод значений из формы-->
    <?php
    function my_fopen($fnam,$fmod)
    {
        $f = fopen($fnam,$fmod);
        if($f === false)
        {
            echo "Unable to open".$fnam."<br>";
            exit(0);
        }
        return $f;
    }
    function my_file($fnam)
    {
        $a = file($fnam);
        if($a === false)
        {
            echo "Unable to read".$fnam."<br>";
            exit(0);
        }
        return $a;
    }


    $fname = "datafile.txt";
    $form1 = array($_POST["logged"], $_POST["fname"], $_POST["sname"], $_POST["mname"], $_POST["sex"], $_POST["Day"], $_POST["Month"], $_POST["Year"], $_POST["tarea"], $_POST["check1"], $_POST["check2"], md5($_POST["pass"]), md5($_POST["passd"]));
    $form2=implode(";&nbsp;",$form1);

    $f = my_fopen($fname,"a+");
    flock($f,LOCK_EX);
    fwrite($f,$form2.".\r\n");
    fflush($f);
    flock($f,LOCK_UN);
    fclose($f);

    $a = my_file($fname);
    foreach($a as $kk=>$vv)

    {
           echo ++$kk.")&nbsp;".$vv;
            echo "<br>";
    }

    ?>
    </div><br>


    <?php else: ?>   <!-- Если условие не выполнено-->
    <span id='sp1'>Пароль и/или логин не введены или неверные!</span><br>

        <form action = "./HWL14_db.php" method = "post"> <!--Вторая форма-->
        <label>Логин: <input id = "log1" class = "ins1" type = "text" name = "logged" placeholder = "Логин" value = "<?php echo $_POST['logged'];?>" required><br><br></label>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Личные данные</legend>
        <label>Фамилия: <input class  = "ins1" id = "fn" type = "text" name = "fname" size = "35" placeholder = "Фамилия"
        onfocus = "this.value = ''"
        value = "<?php echo $_POST['fname'];?>" required></label>
        <label>Имя:<input class = "ins1" id = "sn" type = "text" name = "sname" placeholder = "Имя"
        onfocus="this.value=''"
        value="<?php echo $_POST['sname'];?>" required></label>
        <label>Отчество:<input class="ins1" id="mn" type="text" name="mname" placeholder="Отчество"
        onfocus="this.value=''"
        value="<?php echo $_POST['mname'];?>" required></label><br><br>
            </fieldset><br><br>


        <div class="rad">
        Пол<br>
            <label>M <input id="s1" type="radio" name="sex" value="Мужской" required></label><br>
            <label>Ж <input id="s2" type="radio" name="sex" value="Женский" required></label><br>

        </div><br><br>

        <div class="rad">
        Дата рождения <br>
            День:<select class="ins1" id="d1" name="Day" <? if($_POST['Day']) echo 'selected'; ?> required>
                    <option label="День" value=""></option>
                    <option value="1" <? echo ($_POST['Day']==1)?'selected':''?>>1</option>
                    <option value="2" <? echo ($_POST['Day']==2)?'selected':''?>>2</option>
                    <option value="3" <? echo ($_POST['Day']==3)?'selected':''?>>3</option>
                    <option value="4" <? echo ($_POST['Day']==4)?'selected':''?>>4</option>
                    <option value="5" <? echo ($_POST['Day']==5)?'selected':''?>>5</option>
                    <option value="6" <? echo ($_POST['Day']==6)?'selected':''?>>6</option>
                    <option value="7" <? echo ($_POST['Day']==7)?'selected':''?>>7</option>
                    <option value="8" <? echo ($_POST['Day']==8)?'selected':''?>>8</option>
                    <option value="9" <? echo ($_POST['Day']==9)?'selected':''?>>9</option>
                    <option value="10" <? echo ($_POST['Day']==10)?'selected':''?>>10</option>
                    <option value="11" <? echo ($_POST['Day']==11)?'selected':''?>>11</option>
                    <option value="12" <? echo ($_POST['Day']==12)?'selected':''?>>12</option>
                    <option value="13" <? echo ($_POST['Day']==13)?'selected':''?>>13</option>
                    <option value="14" <? echo ($_POST['Day']==14)?'selected':''?>>14</option>
                    <option value="15" <? echo ($_POST['Day']==15)?'selected':''?>>15</option>
                    <option value="16" <? echo ($_POST['Day']==16)?'selected':''?>>16</option>
                    <option value="17" <? echo ($_POST['Day']==17)?'selected':''?>>17</option>
                    <option value="18" <? echo ($_POST['Day']==18)?'selected':''?>>18</option>
                    <option value="19" <? echo ($_POST['Day']==19)?'selected':''?>>19</option>
                    <option value="20" <? echo ($_POST['Day']==20)?'selected':''?>>20</option>
                    <option value="21" <? echo ($_POST['Day']==21)?'selected':''?>>21</option>
                    <option value="22" <? echo ($_POST['Day']==22)?'selected':''?>>22</option>
                    <option value="23" <? echo ($_POST['Day']==23)?'selected':''?>>23</option>
                    <option value="24" <? echo ($_POST['Day']==24)?'selected':''?>>24</option>
                    <option value="25" <? echo ($_POST['Day']==25)?'selected':''?>>25</option>
                    <option value="26" <? echo ($_POST['Day']==26)?'selected':''?>>26</option>
                    <option value="27" <? echo ($_POST['Day']==27)?'selected':''?>>27</option>
                    <option value="28" <? echo ($_POST['Day']==28)?'selected':''?>>28</option>
                    <option value="29" <? echo ($_POST['Day']==29)?'selected':''?>>29</option>
                    <option value="30" <? echo ($_POST['Day']==30)?'selected':''?>>30</option>
                    <option value="31" <? echo ($_POST['Day']==31)?'selected':''?>>31</option>
                 </select>
            Месяц:<select class="ins1" id="m1" name="Month" <? if($_POST['Month']) echo 'selected'; ?> required>
                    <option label="Месяц" value=""></option>
                    <option value="Январь" <? echo ($_POST['Month']=='Январь')?'selected':''?>>Январь</option>
                    <option value="Февраль" <? echo ($_POST['Month']=='Февраль')?'selected':''?>>Февраль</option>
                    <option value="Март" <? echo ($_POST['Month']=='Март')?'selected':''?>>Март</option>
                    <option value="Апрель" <? echo ($_POST['Month']=='Апрель')?'selected':''?>>Апрель</option>
                    <option value="Май" <? echo ($_POST['Month']=='Май')?'selected':''?>>Май</option>
                    <option value="Июнь" <? echo ($_POST['Month']=='Июнь')?'selected':''?>>Июнь</option>
                    <option value="Июль" <? echo ($_POST['Month']=='Июль')?'selected':''?>>Июль</option>
                    <option value="Август" <? echo ($_POST['Month']=='Август')?'selected':''?>>Август</option>
                    <option value="Сентябрь" <? echo ($_POST['Month']=='Сентябрь')?'selected':''?>>Сентябрь</option>
                    <option value="Октябрь" <? echo ($_POST['Month']=='Октябрь')?'selected':''?>>Октябрь</option>
                    <option value="Ноябрь" <? echo ($_POST['Month']=='Ноябрь')?'selected':''?>>Ноябрь</option>
                    <option value="Декабрь" <? echo ($_POST['Month']=='Декабрь')?'selected':''?>>Декабрь</option>
                  </select>
            Год:<select class="ins1" id="y1" name="Year" <? if($_POST['Year']) echo 'selected'; ?> required>
                    <option label="Год" value=""></option>
                    <option value="1985" <? echo ($_POST['Year']==1985)?'selected':''?>>1985</option>
                    <option value="1986" <? echo ($_POST['Year']==1986)?'selected':''?>>1986</option>
                    <option value="1987" <? echo ($_POST['Year']==1987)?'selected':''?>>1987</option>
                    <option value="1988" <? echo ($_POST['Year']==1988)?'selected':''?>>1988</option>
                    <option value="1989" <? echo ($_POST['Year']==1989)?'selected':''?>>1989</option>
                    <option value="1990" <? echo ($_POST['Year']==1990)?'selected':''?>>1990</option>
                    <option value="1991" <? echo ($_POST['Year']==1991)?'selected':''?>>1991</option>
                    <option value="1992" <? echo ($_POST['Year']==1992)?'selected':''?>>1992</option>
                    <option value="1993" <? echo ($_POST['Year']==1993)?'selected':''?>>1993</option>
                    <option value="1994" <? echo ($_POST['Year']==1994)?'selected':''?>>1994</option>
                    <option value="1995" <? echo ($_POST['Year']==1995)?'selected':''?>>1995</option>
                    <option value="1996" <? echo ($_POST['Year']==1996)?'selected':''?>>1996</option>
                    <option value="1997" <? echo ($_POST['Year']==1997)?'selected':''?>>1997</option>
                    <option value="1998" <? echo ($_POST['Year']==1998)?'selected':''?>>1998</option>
                    <option value="1999" <? echo ($_POST['Year']==1999)?'selected':''?>>1999</option>
                    <option value="2000" <? echo ($_POST['Year']==2000)?'selected':''?>>2000</option>
                    <option value="2001" <? echo ($_POST['Year']==2001)?'selected':''?>>2001</option>
                    <option value="2002" <? echo ($_POST['Year']==2002)?'selected':''?>>2002</option>
                    <option value="2003" <? echo ($_POST['Year']==2003)?'selected':''?>>2003</option>
                    <option value="2004" <? echo ($_POST['Year']==2004)?'selected':''?>>2004</option>
                    <option value="2005" <? echo ($_POST['Year']==2005)?'selected':''?>>2005</option>
                    <option value="2006" <? echo ($_POST['Year']==2006)?'selected':''?>>2006</option>
                    <option value="2007" <? echo ($_POST['Year']==2007)?'selected':''?>>2007</option>
                    <option value="2008" <? echo ($_POST['Year']==2008)?'selected':''?>>2008</option>
                </select>
            <br><br>
            </div>

           <label> Образование:<br>
            <textarea class="ins1" id="t1" name="tarea" placeholder="Образование" onfocus="this.value=''" required>
            </textarea></label><br><br>

            <div class="rad">

            <label><input id="c1" type="checkbox" name="check1" value="Постоянный клиент" <? if($_POST['check1']) echo 'checked'; ?>>Постоянный клиент</label><br>
            <label><input id="c2" type="checkbox" name="check2" value="Посетитель читального зала" <? if($_POST['check2']) echo 'checked'; ?>>Посетитель читального зала</label><br>
            <?php if (!$_POST['check1']&&!$_POST['check2']) {echo "<span class='span1'>Заполните это поле</span>";}?><br>

            </div>

           <label> Пароль: <br><input id = "ps1" class="ins1" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Пароль"
            onfocus="this.value=''"
            value = "<?php echo $_POST['pass']; ?>" required></label><br><br>
            <label>Подтвердить:<br><input class="ins1" id="ps2" type="password" name="passd" placeholder="Подтвердить"
            onfocus="this.value=''"
            value = "<?php echo $_POST['passd'];?>" required></label><br><br>



            <input type="submit" value="Зарегистрировать">
            <input class="but2" type="button" value="Очистить форму" onclick="sb1();"><br><br>

        </form> <!--Вторая форма закрылась-->

        <?php endif;?>  <!-- Конец условия-->



    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вход осуществляется только по логину и паролю,то делать надо так:
1.Получаем содержимое файла в массив `file ()`,таким образом преобразуем все дело в формат строка=>значение

2.Выводим весь массив через `print_r` и смотрим в каких ячейках размещен логин и пароль.Например это может быть ячейка с ключем 4 для логина и 5 для пароля.Соотвенно, можно сразу задать переменные `$log = $mass [4]` `$pass = $mass [5]`

3.Дальше, достаточно проверить данные на соответствие через элементарный `if` и готово.Но не забывайте про безопасность.

4.Можно ещё использовать сессии чтобы не вылазить каждый раз из скрипта.Задаем параметр в `$_SESSION` и записываем дополнительно в файл.Потом тоже сверяем:)

Comment: Почему мой код перебрасывает сразу на другую страницу:

Comment: <?php

 if(isset($_POST['enter']))
 {
  $e_login = $_POST['login'];
  $passw = md5($_POST['passw']);
  
 }
 

 $a = file("datafile.txt");
 for($i = 1; $i<count($a); $i++)
 {
  $users[$i] = explode(";", $a[$i]);
 }
 for($i = 0; $i<count($users); $i++)
  if(($users[$i][0] === $e_login)&&($users[$i][11] === $passw))
  {
   
   echo "<html><head><meta http-equiv = 'refresh' content = '0; URL = ./HWL14_db.php'></head></html>";
  }
  
 ?>

Comment: @лихаим Ну сначала вы шлете данные обработчику. Он проверяет и отдаёт вам HTML контент.Я вижу что в мета прописана переадерсация - может в этом проблема?Для чего это нужно делать было?И да - старайтесь не выводить HTML код через PHP.Мухи отдельно,котлеты тоже